# Specify view to use when ListView is empty?

Tags: android

I can't find this in the docs - isn't there a way to specify a View to use for a ListView if the adapter is empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**`setEmptyView`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) and tell the current `ListView` to display a specific `View` when the adapter is empty, like so

```
getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
```